# Fastest way to create large file in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, bulkinsert

Create a flat text file in c++ around 50 - 100 MB
with the content 'Added first line' should be inserted in to the file for 4 million times

Comment: I guess it all depends on exactly what "text" you want in the file, and what you mean by "best".  Fastest?

I guess that repeatedly writing a buffer containing some sample text will get you there the fastest.  Picking the size of the buffer to get the best speed takes experimenting.

Comment: 'Lakh' is an Indian word for 10,000.

Comment: The original question (which has been radically altered) asked for a block of text repeated in a file, and wanted to know how fast that could be written.  The changed question asks for a single string at the top.  And judging by the answers below it may have had other iterations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

using old style file io

**fopen** the file for write.

**fseek** to the desired file size - 1.

**fwrite** a single byte

**fclose** the file

Comment: 1) forgot the "Added first Line" 
2) does not allocate physically on all OSs / file systems. Some leave the intermediate blocks unallocated. raj should tell if the diskspace really has to be physically allocated or only logically.

Comment: What does 
40 lakhs time
mean?

Comment: Lol.   This addresses the original question.  It's been edited a bit since then.  It needs a new answer.

Comment: If you ever want to do this, 'man truncate' (works on a path) or ftruncate (with open()) which will extend as well as truncate files to a given length.

Answer (score 13):

The fastest way to create a file of a certain size is to simply create a zero-length file using `creat()` or `open()` and then change the size using `chsize()`. This will simply allocate blocks on the disk for the file, the contents will be whatever happened to be in those blocks. It's very fast since no buffer writing needs to take place.

Comment: A good operating system, should zero out all those allocated blocks as a security measure.  I noted Novell Netware doing that circa 1989, so by now, all should.

Comment: that depends on the O/S.  On most Unix systems if you seek to an offset and then write data, you'll end up with a "sparse file" where the intervening blocks don't take up any space on the disk.

Comment: The fact that there aren't actually blocks allocated and filled with zeros is neither here nor there.  Sparse files (on Unix at least) will read as zero, which is the security you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the question.  Do you want to ensure that every character in the file is a printable ASCII character?  If so, what about this?  Fills the file with "abcdefghabc...."

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   const int FILE_SiZE = 50000; //size in KB
   const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
   char buffer [BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
      buffer[i] = (char)(i%8 + 'a');
   buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';

   FILE *pFile = fopen ("somefile.txt", "w");
   for (i = 0; i < FILE_SIZE; i++)
     fprintf(pFile, buffer);

   fclose(pFile);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the OS but I'll assume creat/open/close/write are available.

For truly efficient writing and assuming, say, a 4k page and disk block size and a repeated string:

1. open the file.
2. allocate 4k * number of chars in your repeated string, ideally aligned to a page boundary.
3. print repeated string into the memory 4k times, filling the blocks precisely.
4. Use write() to write out the blocks to disk as many times as necessary.  You may wish to write a partial piece for the last block to get the size to come out right.
5. close the file.

This bypasses the buffering of fopen() and friends, which is good and bad: their buffering means that they're nice and fast, but they are still not going to be as efficient as this, which has no overhead of working with the buffer.

This can easily be written in C++ or C, but does assume that you're going to use POSIX calls rather than iostream or stdio for efficiency's sake, so it's outside the core library specification.

Comment: I really like this answer, however I'm a dumb C freshie, and this feels like a dumb question, but how do we align to a page boundary?.

Comment: 4k pages are evenly spaced starting at 0, so a pointer that divides exactly by 4k is what you want.  So something like char *a=malloc(8192); char *aligned = (char *)(((size_t)a+4096) & ~(size_t)4095) - You can work with  4096-a%4096 if you like, too.  You're aiming for a rounded number higher than a and lower than a+4096 that divides exactly by 4096.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, creating a ~500MB file on Windows very fast.
The larger buffer you pass to fwrite() the fastest you'll be.

```
int i;
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(fname,"wb");

if (fp != NULL) {

    // create big block's data
    uint8_t b[278528]; // some big chunk size

    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(b); i++ ) // custom initialization if != 0x00
    {
        b[i] = 0xFF;
    }

    // write all blocks to file
    for( i = 0; i < TOT_BLOCKS; i++ )
        fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, fp);

    fclose (fp);
}
```

Now at least on my Win7, MinGW, creates file almost instantly.
Compared to fwrite() 1 byte at time, that will complete in 10 Secs.
Passing 4k buffer will complete in 2 Secs.

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest way to create large file in c++?**
Ok.  I assume fastest way means the one that takes the smallest run time.

**Create a flat text file in c++ around 50 - 100 MB with the content 'Added first line' should be inserted in to the file for 4 million times.**

preallocate the file using old style file io

```
fopen the file for write.
fseek to the desired file size - 1.
fwrite a single byte
fclose the file

create a string containing the "Added first line\n" a thousand times.
find it's length.
```

preallocate the file using old style file io

```
fopen the file for write.
fseek to the the string length * 4000
fwrite a single byte
fclose the file

open the file for read/write
loop 4000 times, 
    writing the string to the file.
close the file.
```

That's my best guess.
I'm sure there are a lot of ways to do it.