# How to create file of "x" size?

Tags: c, file-io

How do I set the size of a file in c ? Would I do this after I fopen?

Comment: Look at the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265518/fastest-way-to-create-large-file-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you would do it after fopen - you can create what is know as a sparse file

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        int X = 1024 * 1024 - 1;
        FILE *fp = fopen("myfile", "w");
        fseek(fp, X , SEEK_SET);
        fputc('\0', fp);
        fclose(fp);
}
```

That should create you a file for X Byte for whatever you need, in this case it's 1MiB

Comment: That's 8 times as large as 8Mb. Plus one byte.

Comment: @Ignacio Can you clarify what you mean ?? And how would you make a 1 Mb file?

Comment: Fair enough its 1Mb plus 1 byte where do you get the other 7Mb?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I think he's saying you're conflating your bits (b) and bytes (B).

Comment: WTF - since when did fseek work in bits - name me 1 ISO C99 function that takes bits as an argument

Comment: I can't think of one. But you stated that the file will be 1Mb when instead it will actually be 1MB.

Comment: I think the size will be in chars, which, as we know, have CHAR_BITS bits in them, so, it seems like a portable way of creating a file of a specific number of 8-bit bytes is a little more complex.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams And really it did not account to you that the typo between 'b' and 'B' was more likely than the scenario of me providing a solution in MeagBits.

Comment: @AdrianCornish could you edit to read 1MB instead of 1Mb and 1024*1024-1 for fseek?

Comment: Mb MB and MiB all mean different things. This example creates a file of size 1 MiB. Not 1MB or 1Mb.

Answer (score 11):

Surprised nobody has said this yet - but the easy answer is `ftruncate`, which can be used to increase a file's length as well as decrease it. If increasing the extra file data is set to zero-bytes.

```
FILE *fp=fopen("myfile", "w");
ftruncate(fileno(fp), 1024*1024);
fclose(fp);
```

Note that if you have previously written data beyond the length you are truncating to, you will first need to `fflush` it (see here: [ftruncate on file opened with fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494417/ftruncate-on-file-opened-with-fopen)).

`ftruncate` info: http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate.

Comment: [Somebody did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775127/1287112), two years before you.  Upvoted anyway, though. :)

Answer (score 5):

The only way in *plain standard C* is to write `x` bytes to the file after opening it *in binary mode*, and even then, the standard allows an implementation to append an arbitrary number of null bytes to the end without telling you.

On the other hand, with **POSIX**, it's easy. Simply call `ftruncate(fileno(f), x);`

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify your question?  Do you mean you're trying to create a new file with a particular size or you have an existing file and you want to truncate it?

Truncating an existing file is easy (in Unix variants, anyway) -- use the truncate() function.

For creating the new file - I'm not sure exactly what you'd be asking.  Do you want to create a file that's empty but has a particular size?  Why would you need to do that?  The sparse file technique that others have described (fseek + fputc) creates a "sparse" file that takes up almost no space on disk, but (if you read it) returns all 0s.

Comment: I'd like set the size of a file. much like Adrian suggested I "believe".

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it - when I asked you to clarify what you mean by "how do I set the size of the file" you repeated "I'd like to set the size of the file."  Can you clarify what you mean exactly, and describe in more detail what you're doing?

Comment: create a file that's empty but has a particular size. Sorry for the vague response

Comment: @Questioneer: What exactly do you mean by "empty"?  Normally, a file with a non-zero size is not empty.  A file (on typical systems) is a sequence of zero or more bytes, and each of those bytes has a value.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on what you mean by "empty but has a particular size".  Do you mean it contains all 0s?  Do you mean a sparse file?  Do you mean a file whose space has been allocated on disk?  We need more context to answer this question sensibly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of ways to do this:

1 . C/C++ only

You can move the file pointer (using `fseek()`) to the size you want, and write anything. This will set the size of the file to the location of the file pointer.

However, this approach only lets you increase the size of a file. It doesn't not let you shrink it.

2 . (Windows)

You can make the file using `CreateFile()`, then set the file pointer location and use [`SetEndOfFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the actual size.

This method in Windows can also be used to shrink the size of a file.

3 . (Linux)

To shrink the size of a file call `ftruncate(fileno(f),size)` or `truncate(path,size)`.