# ftruncate on file opened with fopen

Tags: c, linux

Platform is Ubuntu Linux on ARM.
I want to write a string to a file, but I want every time to truncate the file and then write the string, i.e. no append.

I have this code:

```
f=fopen("/home/user1/refresh.txt","w");
fputs( "{"some string",f);
fflush(f);
ftruncate(fileno(f),(off_t)0);
flcose(f);
```

If I run it and then check the file, it will be of zero length and when opened, there will be nothing in it. 
If I remove the `fflush` call, it will NOT be 0 (will be 11) and when I open it there will be "some string" in it.
Is this the normal behavior?
I do not have a problem calling `fflush`, but I want to do this in a loop and calling `fflush` may increase the execution time considerably.

Comment: If you don't flush the buffer, it can happen that it is only flushed on `fclose`, after truncating.

Answer (score 5):

You should not really mix file handle and file descriptor calls like that.

What's almost certainly happening without the fflush is that the `some string` is waiting in file handle buffers for delivery to the file descriptor. You then truncate the file descriptor and fclose the file handle, flushing the string, hence it shows up in the file.

*With* the fflush, `some string` is sent to the file descriptor and *then* you truncate it. With no further flushing, the file stays truncated.

Comment: What can I do, one function takes a file handle, the other takes a descriptor?

Comment: What can I do, one function takes a handle, the other takes a descriptor? As for the sequence of events I thought that in case of no "fflush" both the "fputs" and truncate will be queued and when the file is closed 1. the string will be written and 2. file will be truncated.

Comment: @user1523271, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. There are a number of ways you can do it, such as what you have or closing and re-opening with `"w"` mode. You should phrase your question as a business need rather than a technical option. That way, the number of possible solutions is greatly expanded. In other words, step back and tell us _what_ you want to achieve rather than _how._

Comment: This 'queueing' by the way is a property of the file handle. When you ftruncate, you're effectively bypassing the queue. That's what's happening here.

Comment: Great explanation. But I disagree that it's fundamentally wrong to mix file handle and file descriptor calls. There's odd behaviour (like this) to be aware of, but it's not inherently bad practice, and sometimes you have no choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to literally "truncate the file then write", then it's sufficient to:

```
f=fopen("/home/user1/refresh.txt","w");
fputs("some string",f);
fclose(f);
```

Opening the file in the mode `w` will truncate it (as opposed to mode `a` which is for appending to the end).

Also calling `fclose` will flush the output buffer so no data gets lost.

Comment: I thought about this, but I cant do it, this code will be called in a loop and have heard that opening and closing a file is an expensive operation and as such, it will introduce delays

Answer (score 2):

POSIX requires you to take specific actions (which ensure that no ugly side effects of buffering make your program go haywire) when switching between using a FILE stream and a file descriptor to access the same open file. This is described in [XSH 2.5.1 Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01).

In your case, I believe it should suffice to just call `fflush` before `ftruncate`, like you're doing. Omitting this step, per the rules of 2.5.1, results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Since I am going to call "fflush", is it going to be expensive time-wise?

Comment: Not any moreso that the fundamental cost of what you're trying to do.