# ftruncate is not working properly with msys2

Tags: c, truncate, msys2

I'm trying to modify the size of a file. I'm working with msys2. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void dummy_file(){
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* print some text */
    const char *text = "Write this to the file";
    fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

    /* print integers and floats */
    int i = 1;
    float py = 3.1415927;
    fprintf(f, "Integer: %d, float: %f\n", i, py);

    /* printing single chatacters */
    char c = 'A';
    fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c);
    fclose(f);
}

void print_size(){
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    long sz = 0;
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(f);
    printf("%ld\n",sz);
    fclose(f);
}

void truncate_file(){
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ftruncate(fileno(f), 40);
    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Begin\n");
    dummy_file();
    print_size();
    // truncate_file();
    print_size();
    printf("End\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

Begin
   80
   40
   End

The file has changed to 40 bytes but the content is plenty of null values.

I'm doing something wrong? Is there an alternative to truncate the file while maintaining its content?

Comment: If you're going to use POSIX `ftruncate()`, you might as well just get an `int` file descriptor directly with POSIX `int fd = open( "file.txt", O_WRONLY );`, then if the `open()` succeeded call `ftruncate( fd, 40 ); close( fd );`  You should also check the return value from `ftruncate()` in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file with `fopen` on `w` mode you truncate the file to zero length. After that, when you run `ftruncate` it will fill the file with `\0` to get to the size you specified.

From `fopen` man page,

> w      Truncate file to zero length or create text  file  for  writing.
>          The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

You can instead open it with `r+` mode, which doesn't truncate the file if it exists and allows for writing as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void dummy_file(){
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* print some text */
    const char *text = "Write this to the file";
    fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

    /* print integers and floats */
    int i = 1;
    float py = 3.1415927;
    fprintf(f, "Integer: %d, float: %f\n", i, py);

    /* printing single chatacters */
    char c = 'A';
    fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c);
    fclose(f);
}

void print_size(){
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    long sz = 0;
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(f);
    printf("%ld\n",sz);
    fclose(f);
}

void truncate_file(){
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ftruncate(fileno(f), 40);
    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Begin\n");
    dummy_file();
    print_size();
    truncate_file();
    print_size();
    printf("End\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Just a side note to consider when expanding your code: Mixing file descriptor and STD I/O Streams can result in undefined behavior if some steps aren't followed (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13495706/6676042) which points to [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01) for more information).