# create fixed length text file in C?

Tags: c, file-io

What is the best way to create a empty text file of given length in C? Writing space or any special char is not an option. I mean it should directly create the file without any iteration up to file length or something.

Comment: The length of the text file depends on the number of characters in it.  Writing space or some special character like '0' is the only possibility

Comment: The length of an empty file is 0...

Comment: An "empty" file has length 0. If it has a given length, it is not empty, and you must decide what you want to put in it. Probably zeroes, but that's up to you. And you'll need to write that into the file. If the size is not too big, just a malloc, memset, write will suffice. If the size is quite large, you'll have to loop.

Comment: @jcaron Not 100% true. I agree about defining a file as "empty", but allocating lots of memory and writing that to the file isn't necessary, unless you want to "initialize" the file contents as well.

Comment: then I guess writing is the only option.

Comment: @suri See my answer, in case you won't need any special content set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty trivial to do. All you have to do is to seek the intended position and then write something:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned int wanted_size = 1048576;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.dat", "w+");
    if (fp) {
        // Now go to the intended end of the file
        // (subtract 1 since we're writing a single character).
        fseek(fp, wanted_size - 1, SEEK_SET);
        // Write at least one byte to extend the file (if necessary).
        fwrite("", 1, sizeof(char), fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The example above will create a file that is 1 MB in length. Just keep in mind that the actual space will be allocated immediately, not just reserved.

This will also allow you to allocate files larger than your system memory. With the code above I'm able to instantly (< 1 ms) reserve a 1 GB large file on a Raspberry Pi (which only has 512 MB RAM) without having to use any kind of iteration.

You're also able to use any other way to write data to the position (like `fputs()`), it's just important that you actually write something. Calling `fputs("", fp);` won't necessarily extend the file as intended.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows use [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on Linux use [truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) (which also increases).

Comment: on Linux "truncate" will only modify the size of the file as requested by the user. It will not create a empty file with set size.

Comment: @Santosh yes you have to create the file first, then set its size with these.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with.

```
// hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int CreateFileSetSize(const char *file, int size)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(file, "w");
    if (NULL == pFile)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(pFile, size, SEEK_SET);
    fputc('\n', pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const char *fileName = "MyFile.txt";
    int size = 1024;
    int ret = 0;
    if (3 == argc)
    {
        fileName = argv[1];
        size = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    ret = CreateFileSetSize(fileName, size);
    return ret;
}
```

I apparently am not the only one to come up with this solution. I happened to find the following question right here on Stack Overflow.

*How to create file of “x” size?*
[How to create file of "x" size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775027/how-to-create-file-of-x-size)